How to forward declare a role to be used for an enum?
Running this piece of code
use v6.d;

role DrawSurface { ... };

enum Surface does DrawSurface <Fire>;

role DrawSurface {
    method draw () {
        given self {
            when Surface::Fire { "f" }
        }
    }
}

Produces this error:
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling /tmp/me.raku
No appropriate parametric role variant available for 'DrawSurface':
    Cannot resolve caller (Surface:U); Routine does not have any candidates.  Is only the proto defined?
at /tmp/me.raku:5

How do I write that so that I can do this: Surface::Fire.draw?

Anyone know why liz deleted her answer? (Saved in a gist so everyone can see it.) I get that Dmitry (hi Dmitry) has done a nice QA combo, so she perhaps didn't want to "compete", but her answer still seemed very useful.

A very welcome addition, I really like this answer too, thank you for saving it. Regarding competing, I just wanted to make this question answered online for others, no other attachments to the QA combo :^) Lizmat is very welcome to post her solution

Direct solution using multidispatch.
module DrawSurface {
    enum Surface is export <Fire>;

    proto draw (Surface $ ) is export {*}
    multi draw (Fire) {'f'}
}

import DrawSurface;

say draw Fire;

f

Combination with role.
role DrawSurface {
    method draw () {drawp self}
}

enum Surface does DrawSurface <Fire>;

multi drawp(Fire) { 'f' }

say Fire.draw;

f


nice! - particularly the second variant with role

Enums are compile time constructs, so all logic to create the enum must exist when the enum is declared.
The closest solution is to do like this
use v6.d;

enum Surface <Fire>;

role DrawSurface {
    method draw ($surface) {
        given $surface {
            when Surface::Fire { "f" }
        }
    }
}

say DrawSurface.draw(Fire);

or like this
use v6.d;

enum Surface <Fire>;

class SurfaceC {
    has Surface $.surface;

    method draw {
        given $!surface {
            when Surface::Fire { "f" }
        }
    }
}

say SurfaceC.new(surface => Fire).draw;

